# Change color of URLs/hyperlinks in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

How do I change the color of URLs and/or hyperlinks in Notepad++? Is there a setting for this?

Comment: In what kind of file? Have you configured your theme using the Style Configurator yet? Sounds like you need to read [the documentation](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/themes/).

Comment: Though, looking at it, I'm not sure you can. You can turn off the underline, and you can set hover styling, but beyond that it's just normal text. Have you considered discussing this with the Notepad++ team?

Comment: [Seems to be deliberate](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/post/56191)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Thanks for the answers!

Yes, I have found several methods on how to change the color of URL that I am hovering over, but not when unhovered.

It seems like URLs/hyperlinks can indeed be identified. They are underlined. Sadly, I having found an option to change the color of them yet.